# How does the sitelink search box work?

Tags: javascript

I have a website. I want a search box to appear under the main page of my website in google. I have my own custom search engine and search bar in the website. I did a bit of research and found out that you need a chunk of code like this:

```
<script type=”application/ld+json”>
    {
      “@context”: “http://schema.org”,

      “@type”: “WebSite”,

      “url”: “https://www.panpact.com/”,

        “potentialAction”: {

        “@type”: “SearchAction”,

        “target”: “https://query.panpact.com/searchresults.php?search={search_term_string}&page=1&con=1”,

        “query-input”: “required name=search_term_string”

         }
    }
    </script>
```

I have changed the above code to replace example with my website name(Panpact).
I am not sure if it works though. When someone on my site searches and presses enter they are redirected to the search page and the url looks like:

```
http://panpact.com/searchresults.php?search=Hello&page=1&con=1
```

First of all is my above Script code correct for what I want to do? And why is their the word query in front of the domain in the target field? Do I need it?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the actual site usage by the user. this is to inform web crawlers that there is a a website, and it has a search page